# Find last attachment in a channel Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making an image edit command, I am trying to find the last image in a channel but when I run it it says that url1 is undefined code below.

```
const url1 = msg.channel.lastMessage.attachments.url;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the first attachment, as `message.attachments` is an array:

```js
msg.channel.messages.fetch().then((messages) => {
    const lastMessage = messages.sort((a, b) => b.createdTimestamp - a.createdTimestamp).filter((m) => m.attachments.size > 0).first();
    const url1 = lastMessage.attachments[0].url;
});
```

Comment: Okay, it should now handle ALL the specific cases ^^